# Magento Image Clean extension error

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, magento

I am not a magento expert so dont know any thing about coding or decoding. I have been using magento Image clean extension for a long time. but suddenly it start giving this error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action' not found in /var/www/vhosts/smartchoice786.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Imaclean/controllers/Adminhtml/ImacleanController.php on line 4`

I dont know what this file is calling here which is missing. I have tried to uninstall and install again the extension but no use. read the whole file on above location but can not see any problem.

If you guys can help it would be much appreciated.

Kindest Regards

Comment: Can you try making the A of Action uppercase? ie: `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`, that should solve the issue.

Comment: ok let me try i will let you know in a minute

Comment: it did work, thank you, thank you very much. it was an easy fix.

Comment: but now it isnt showing any images. any idea why not searching for images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, adding the solution on an answer, so that the question is not pending to solve.

To solve the problem, change the name of the extended class from `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action` to `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`.

Comment: hi, but now it isnt showing the images. i know there are plenty of extra images are in my data base. as i deleted every thing from my admin panel. can you tell me if it is calling the right file?

Comment: This change shouldn't affect the functionality of the extension, it either loads the file or fails. Does the extension has any settings that might be reseted when you re-installed it?